# paypal sandbox account with currency US or GB can't receive EUR

Tags: wordpress, paypal, currency, paypal-adaptive-payments

what seems like being simple is driving me crazy :
I have a website (wordpress + woocommerce). I sell products in euros on it. I have different paypal accounts to which money is sent (adaptive parallel payments) : I have one of them which is a US one, and another which is a GB ones.
When I try to make payment in euros, those two accounts don't receive anything.
When I swich my conf to any of these currencies (GB and US), it works for their respective countries and not for euros.

I don't have any souvenir that you cannot get paied in another currency than yours.

Why is that ? Is it only in the sandbox ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any error while trying to process the Payments in EURO?

Answer (score 0):

sorry for being late, and here's the answer :
Actually when trading in a different currency, the account which receives the payment has to "accept" it in the trade's details.
Not obvious but this is it, and it works like a charm.